# Setting PHP session on index page for XSRF check

Tags: php, angularjs, session, csrf

I have run in to the following problem regarding XSRF tokens.

Client: AngularJS
Server: PHP

When the index.php is hit, PHP generates an XSRF token and saves it in a session.
A cookie is set with same value.

AngularJS reads the cookie and stores the value.

On subsequent POSTS, the XSRF token is sent as a header, and the idea is to compare the stored session token to the sent header.

Everything seems fine, no problems whatsoever.

BUT: the issue is, that PHP cannot read the session registered in index.php, because technically there have been no page reloads! If I hit F5 and reloads everything , the session is read nicely.

How can I set the XSRF Session token on index.php and have it available for subsequent ajax requests from the client?? I'm pulling out my hair on this one... appreciate feedback.

**UPDATE**

After changing the session identifier name, everything suddenly worked!

In index.php:

```
// Create token and set session
session_start();
$token = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$_SESSION['XSRF']=$token;
```

Later, also in index.php:

```
/* Give token to Angular client */
<script>
angular.module("app").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?=$_SESSION['XSRF'];?>'); 
</script>
```

Note that I'm not using a cookie, instead I set a constant which is then made available to the .run method in Angular:

in Angular:

```
angular.module('app').run(['CSRF_TOKEN','$http',function(CSRF_TOKEN,$http) {

   $http.defaults.headers.common['CSRF_TOKEN'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
```

All requests to the server are routed to one common php file. The file checks if the header is set, and compares the two tokens:

```
// Only POST requests are checked (I don't use PUT/DELETE)
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
   session_start();
   $headerToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_CSRF_TOKEN'];
   $sessionToken = $_SESSION['XSRF'];
   if($headerToken!=$sessionToken){
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you posting to index.php in your $http calls or some other php page on your server? If I understand your problem, it's that the php file gets an empty session?

Comment: If I understand correctly... You can generate the XSRF token variable with PHP and put into JS code if you want it to be available for ajax requests... Perhaps some example code of yours would help?

Comment: There's no reason for this not to work. On the first request you create a session and a token and return the session cookie with your first response. The session exists now, all subsequent requests have an active session. We'd need more details to help you here.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies. I'll try to put out some code later, but bascially I'm NOT posting to the same index.php file. All Ajax requests are posted to the same, common php page. I'm checking for the session and it's just not there.... until page reload.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry to have taken your time. It now works for me, but the funny thing is that I haven't changed much. I changed the name of the session variable and suddenly everything worked.. weird..

Comment: ARggh dammit it still doesn't work.. going crazy

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I can't access php sessions either between pages until I manually refresh the page.

Comment: Question about the UPDATE: by providing the token as an Angular constant, aren't you also allowing malicious JavaScript to read the token easily as well?  That's why the token was locked inside a cookie, so that it was not readable by non-origin JavaScript executing on your current page with access to the DOM.  Or am I missing something fundamental to how a const is made available to client-side JS that protects it against such malicious code?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I'm doing in my PHP/AngularJS projects:

index.php

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'])) {
    $uniqueValues = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //add more/less/any "unique" values, see comments
    $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'] = sha1(uniqid(microtime() . $uniqueValues, true));
    setcookie('XSRF-TOKEN', $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN']);
}
```

any script called by AngularJS $http:
(AngluarJS uses the value of the cookie XSRF-TOKEN and will send it in every request as X-XSRF-TOKEN custom header, so we need to compare this value to the value stored in the session.)

```
function verifyXSRF() {

    /*
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $headerToken = "";
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        if ($header == "X-XSRF-TOKEN") {
            $headerToken = $value;
            break;          
        }
    }
    */

    //more efficient, see comments
    $headerToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'];

    if ($headerToken != $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN']) return false;
    return true;
}

session_start();
if (!verifyXSRF()) die("XSRF error");
```

Feedback welcome as I don't know exactly if this is enough XSRF protection.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This is also bascially how I do it. By the way, an easier way to check for the occurance of the http header, is just to use $headerToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_XSRF_TOKEN'], no need to loop through all of headers. Also remember that Angular only sends the header on POST, PUT and DELETE requests, not on GET

Comment: I suggest to put something more unique that microtime() as the "random" generator, for example, placing the user's ID, IP address, accessed page, etc, will increase the complexity and make it harder to guess the XSRF-TOKEN. I also suggest to minimize the exposure of the cookie, by using httponly (if possible) and path parameters

Comment: Also, you don't have to create a cookie for Angular to read. Just set a CONSTANT (see my update)

Comment: Is this considered as safe as using a cookie?

Comment: Don't see why not? It's injected into AngularJS - and only provided on the index.php page...

Comment: Hi again, I was wondering why you check for the existance of $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'] before creating it.. why not always create it nomatter what? If the client refreshes the page, he will get a new XSRF-TOKEN instead of the old - which should be a bit more secure. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: I just had the issue if both, the header token and the token from the cookie are not available, it returns true because both are the same (not available). So currently I'm checking if they are available: `code:  if (!$headerToken || !$_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'] || $headerToken != $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN'])
  return false;`

Comment: A shorter and improved version of the verifyXSRF function: `function verifyXSRF() { return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'] === $_SESSION['XSRF-TOKEN']; }`