# csrf token where to store for angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, cookies, csrf

Before taking advantage of amazing AngularJS, I used to store the CSRF Token in the Sessions variable in PHP. My CSRF Validation is ready and works when using it with the sessions. However, the problem is AngularJS cannot access the PHP Session variable to get the token. Where should I store them? Is storing them in the cookies safe? What is the most secure way to approach this? Maybe I should generate token and store them in both session and cookies and then check the cookie against the session and then renew the token once its used?

Comment: you can check out this link below. [`Cookies vs Tokens. Getting auth right with Angular.JS`](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196737/setting-php-session-on-index-page-for-xsrf-check for a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer storing it in a an angular service, because cookies can be accessed easily.
while sending an XHR , append the token and send.

Also maintain a copy in session, you must check on server side. We should not trust any request from any client, we must always code like the request is sent by an attacker. And we should handle them on server side

**Edit:**

You can read about services here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

```
angular.module('app').service("Auth", function () {
    return {
       csrfToken: "some token"
    }
})
```

In controller you can inject this service and

```
angular.module('app').controller("someController",
  function ($http, Auth) { // injecting Auth service
    $http({method: 'POST', url: "http://example.com/users/1",
         xsrfHeaderName: "csrfToken", 
         header: {csrfToken: Auth.csrfToken} }) // token taken from angular service
  })
```

if you want to store in cookies. you can do this

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: "http://example.com/users/1", 
    xsrfCookieName: "name of cookie in which you stored the token"}) 
                     // fill cookie name
```

Comment: If you do store them in an angular service, how do you fetch them from the server in the first place? So, after reading your post, I am thinking of creating a token and storing it in sessions and cookies, and then the angular would access the cookie, append it to the HTTP header on post request and the validation would happen between the header and the session... Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yep, you can get token from server. set some url like `/api/csrftoken` and store the token in the angular service. Or you can store in cookies. if you think cookies are secure enough